# using AngularJS html5mode with nodeJS and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I'm using a nodeJS server with Express to serve my AngularJS application. This all works fine when I'm using angularJS default routes (hashbangs), but now I'm trying to activate html5 mode.

I'm activating html5mode like this:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

And this is what my nodeJS `app.js` file looks like:

```
var path     = require('path'),
    express  = require('express'),
    app      = express(),
    routes   = require(path.join(__dirname, 'routes'));

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.compress());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.all("/*", function(req, res, next) {
        res.sendfile("index.html", { root: __dirname + "/../app" });
    });
    app.use(express.errorHandler({
        dumpExceptions: true, 
        showStack: true
    }));
});
```

However, this now serves all requests as my `index.html` file, and so I get the following error from requireJS:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I tried adding the following to my nodeJS `app.js` so it would serve my resources correctly:

```
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + "/../app/js"));
app.use("/img", express.static(__dirname + "/../app/img"));
app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + "/../app/css"));
app.use("/partials", express.static(__dirname + "/../app/partials"));
```

but still no luck.

I also tried replacing the `app.all` statement with:

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
  // Use res.sendfile, as it streams instead of reading the file into memory.
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/../app/index.html');
});
```

but that didn't work either. What can I do to get angularJS html5mode working with nodeJS and Express? Thanks.

Comment: It is possible you were seeing the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ` because the path was not being found as expected.  Instead of serving back the Javascript (or CSS, etc.) file you wanted, the 'catch all /*' route was being triggered and sending back the HTML instead.

Comment: app has no method 'configure'

Comment: The `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ` is caused because your angular js app file is not being loaded.  Check the routes to your js directory.  You will probably want to change them from `/` to `/public` or to some other name which is more unique than `/`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your initial fix (declaring static middleware handlers for specific prefixes) should work just fine, but you need to make sure they are declared *before* any other routes (and `app.router`, although you don't need to explicitly use it):

```
// these need to go first:
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + "/../app/js"));
app.use("/img", express.static(__dirname + "/../app/img"));
app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + "/../app/css"));
app.use("/partials", express.static(__dirname + "/../app/partials"));

// any other routes:
app.all("/*", ...);
```

Also, you need to make sure that the prefixed static handlers are actually declared okay (correct path), otherwise they won't be able to find any requested files and the requests will pass down the middleware chain and ultimately be handled by the catch-all handler (should be easy enough to test by commenting out the catch-all handler and see if any JS/CSS/... requests work okay).

Comment: exactly, and if you're using a proxy server like NGINX then you might as well set the dependency routing at the proxy level

Answer (score 10):

Configure express 4 server like:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

and angular like:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'templates/main.html'
        })
        .state('register', {
            url: '/register',
            templateUrl: 'templates/register.html'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a web application using Angularjs and Requirejs on the client, with Nodejs on the server.

Here is some sample code to show you how I set it up.

> Note this example is showing a hash url but you can easily change that by modifying the middleware function and angular configuration

#### Middleware function

```
isXHR: function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.xhr || req.get("angular-request") === "ajaxRequest") {
        next();
    } else {
        var url = req.url;
        var urls = url.split("/");
        var last = _.last(urls);
        urls = _.without(urls, last);
        url = urls.join("/") + "#/" + last //remove the hash if you want to make it html5mode;

        res.redirect(url);
    }
}
```

#### Server route configuration

```
//I'm using express-namespace to group my routes
app.namespace("/requirements", function(){
   //Shared local variable used across the application
   var info = {
        app: {
            title: "Requirements",
            module: "app/requirements" // where the angular application stored
        }
    }
    //this is the main url that will user request
    Route.get("/", function (req, res) {
        res.cookie("profileRegisterationSteps", 0);
        res.render("app/requirements/index", info);
    });
   //this is the url angular js will request
    Route.get("type", filters.isXHR, function (req, res) {
        res.render("app/requirements/profile/type", info);
    });
 })
```

#### Client route configuration

```
require(['App', 'underscore', 'ngAmd'/*angular amd*/, 'autoload'/*No Sense*/, 'appLoader' /*i used to load my scripts file for the route user requested (not all scripts files only who requested) before template laoded*/, 'appRoute'/*this is a list of routes*/], function (app, _, amd, autoload, loader, routes) {

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    //remove a clearn URL
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

    //ku dar header kan si uu server ka u ogaado Request in yahay Ajax
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['angular-request'] = "ajaxRequest";

    //Route Config
    var Route = $routeProvider;
    //get all routes objects that defined in routes module
    _.each(routes, function (route) {
        // extend the routes module objects and use its properties
        Route.when(route.url, _.extend(route, {
            //call returning function in loader module and write the promise
            resolve: _.extend(loader(route))
        }));
    });
    Route.otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    });

});

  //start the application
  amd.bootstrap(app);
 });
```

#### Apploader file

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        //pages
       type: "Apps/requirements/pages/type"
   }
});
 define(['App'], function(app) {
    return function (options) {
      return {
        loader: function ($q, $rootScope) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            var module = options.name// the name of the route (this name corresponds to the requirejs module name above;

            if (!!(module)) {
                if (require.defined(module)) {
                    defer.resolve();
                } else {
                    require([module], function () {
                        $rootScope.safeApply(function () {
                            defer.resolve();
                        })
                    });
                }
            } else {
                defer.resolve();
            }

            return defer.promise;
        }
      }
    }
 });
```

#### Routes file

```
define(function(){
  return {
     {
        name        : "type",
        url         : "/",
        templateUrl : "/requirements/type",
        view        : 'services'
    }

 }

})
```