# Make angular page refresh without Hash links?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I get angular to page refresh without Hash links? On page refresh my angular app would error and not show the page it was just displaying, so I changed the `html5Mode` to `false` ( `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix("");` ) and now I can refresh the page. But I'm also getting the nasty prefix `#/` in the link path.

How do I remove # in the url path while at the same time be able to refresh the page?

Comment: do you have a `<base>` tag in your `<head>`? Also, are you using version 1.3+?

Comment: What is your backend technology?

Comment: @salniro yes to both questions.

Comment: @arman1991 node server.

Comment: Maybe this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777967/using-angularjs-html5mode-with-nodejs-and-express) about configuration can push you forward. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server rewrite will work on refresh, try to add middleware in your server.
Sample grunt configuration id below.
check https://github.com/parmod-arora/angular-url-rewrite for nginx and grunt serve rewrite.

```
middleware: function (connect) {<br>
        var middlewares = [];<br>
        middlewares.push(modRewrite([
          '!/assets|\\.html|\\.js|\\.css|\\woff|\\ttf|\\swf$ /index.html'
        ]));

        middlewares.push(connect.static('.tmp'));
        middlewares.push(connect().use(
          '/bower_components',
          connect.static('./bower_components')
        ));
        middlewares.push(connect.static(appConfig.app));

        //middlewares.push(require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest);
        return middlewares;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Explore this thread: 
[$location / switching between html5 and hashbang mode / link rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting?lq=1)

You need to make sure all your links are absolute relative to `index.html` and you probably need a server rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting base in the head section of your html?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <base href="/">
</head>
```