# System is not defined with Router Parameter - Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, express, typescript, angular2-routing

I am trying to implement routing with id parameter on the url such as localhost:1000/register/id
Using that path will always trigger system is not defined while other urls without parameters are working fine. I even tried following the guide from angular.io's routing format doesn't seems to fix the problem. What am I missing in my code?

[image]

app.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RegisterComponent } from './registration/register.component';
import { CodeComponent } from './registration/code.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'register/:id',
        component: RegisterComponent
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: CodeComponent
    }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CodeComponent } from './registration/code.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './registration/register.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, routing],
    declarations: [AppComponent, CodeComponent, RegisterComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    path = require('path'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 1000;

db = require('./config/db');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(db.url);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'test',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
require('./config/passport')(passport);
require('./routes/main')(app, passport);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(path.join(__dirname+ '/node_modules')));
console.log(path.join(__dirname+ '/node_modules'))

app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('/view/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

UPDATE:

By using this.router.navigate(['/register', '1']); works perfectly, but by typing on the url localhost:1000/register/1 is not working

[image]

From the picture above, there is mouse hover showing the url to be 
localhost:1000/register/node_modules/core-js....
- I think there is something I've missed in my server NodeJS side.

I've also added

```
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
```

But no changes

Note:
Server side (NodeJS,Express)

Comment: how you're navigating got `register/:id`?

Comment: at the moment i'll just type in the url localhost:1000/register/1 to test

Comment: @PankajParkar , I took your question into testing, using this.router.navigate(['/register', '1']); works. But shouldn't by typing on the URL do the same? will update the question

Comment: were you using `html5mode`?

Comment: @PankajParkar <base href="/"> yes

Comment: I guess you have to configure you server to work for any URL, so that your client side should not conflict with server side routing.. which platform you're using on server side?

Comment: @GeneLim, Could you add a screenshot of the error? And how you are building your angular 2 app? With angular-cli or starter repo?

Comment: @PankajParkar Nodejs express.

Comment: @Timathon , updated the question with the screenshot error. i am using start repo with nodejs as my server

Comment: @GeneLim I guess [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17783295/2435473) would help you

Comment: Seems something to do with system.config.js. But I know nothing about that. I'm learning angular 2 with angular-cli, which handles quite a lot in serving, building...

Comment: @PankajParkar Looking into it.

Comment: @PankajParkar could you make it into a solution that I can accept as answer.

Comment: @GeneLim I guess that should have worked, correct?

Comment: @PankajParkar That should be the solution, but it is not working yet. Still finding a way around it.

Comment: @GeneLim see until it get worked. I'd suggest you to have this question open.. Let wait for opinion from other fellows as well

Comment: @PankajParkar Will do, updated with new image, the routing of the server side seems to be the problem.