# why i got page not found when i refresh browser on angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am using ng-route with html5 mode and http-server in npm. I have a main page with ng-view, and when i click on a link the view displays fine. But when i refresh only view display with out header. Below is

```js
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        //console.log($routeProvider);
        $routeProvider.
            when('/app/gateways', {
               templateUrl: '/app/gateways.html',
            }).
            when('/app/lights', {
               templateUrl: '/app/lights.html',
            }).
            when('/app/control', {
               templateUrl: '/app/assign-gateway-to-user.html',
            })
            //otherwise({
            //   redirectTo: '/app/index.html'
            //});
    }])
    .config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider)
    {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false,
        });
    }])
```

Comment: using html5Mode requires  URL rewriting on server side

Comment: How i use URL rewriting in http-server ? Can you explain more to me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777967/using-angularjs-html5mode-with-nodejs-and-express see it

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this. You don't have to define config again to inject new providers. You can do that in a single step

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
   //console.log($routeProvider);
   $locationProvider.html5Mode({
       enabled: true,
       requireBase: false,
   });
   $routeProvider.
   when('/app/gateways', {
       templateUrl: '/app/gateways.html',
   }).
   when('/app/lights', {
       templateUrl: '/app/lights.html',
   }).
   when('/app/control', {
           templateUrl: '/app/assign-gateway-to-user.html',
       })
       //otherwise({
       //   redirectTo: '/app/index.html'
       //});
 }])
```